# Sistema de rank usando MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Estou com uma grande dificuldade para usar o `aggregate` do *MongoDB*.

Preciso pegar 5 usuarios que coletou mais itens.

```
username: 'gg_Max',
items: [
    {
      encrypt: "WccmGN3k6vpbfcdVuWmhTT",
      results: {
        collected: [
          "0082",
          "0012"
        ],
        removed: []
      }
    }
]
```

no caso seria `items.results.collected` pegar o tamanho do Array?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$items" },

    { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$_id", 
            collected:{
               $addToSet: "$items.results.collected"
            },
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$collected" },

    {
        $project: {
          totalcoletado: {
              $size: "$collected" 
          }
       }
    },

    {$sort: { totalcoletado: -1 } },

    {$limit: 5}
])
```